# Usage of “short”

Tags: word-usage

Let’s say that I had a hundred dollars and I spent ten dollars in this case can I use “short” in sentence below?

> My money get ten dollars short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The use of "short" in the context of money means "less than required"

> I'm short on cash, so I can't buy a drink.
>
> The dress costs $60, but you've only given my $50, so you're $10 short.

In the example you give, there is no shortage of money.

Simple ways to express your example:

> I've spent ten dollars.
>
> I'm down ten dollars (This sounds like what you might say if you had lost $10 while gambling)
>
> I've got $90 left.

However, if you wanted to buy something that was worth $100, then you could say

> I can't afford it! I'm short by $10. (or) I'm $10 short.

Comment: Typo: *I've spend ten dollars* -> spent