# How short your payment is?

Tags: questions

What is the question for the sentence below?

> Your payment is ten dollars short.

Would it be correct to say;

> How short is your payment?

Comment: "Short" can refer to the amount of time as well as money. "How short is your payment?" Answer: "By tonight!" So one might ask "How much is the payment short?"

Comment: See: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/239425/usage-of-short